# Syntax for lazy pattern matching with `as` syntax

Tags: haskell, ghci

In (vanilla) GHCi 8.6.5 following function was prefectly valid:

```
f xs@ ~(x:xt) = xs
```

If I now do the same in 9.0.1 I get an error

```
Suffix occurrence of @. For an as-pattern, remove the leading whitespace.
```

Just removing the white space between `@` and `~` doesn't seem to suffice, as then `@~` would be interpreted as an operator, so the only valid variation I found was

```
f xs@(~(x:xt)) = xs
```

I'd like to know the following, for which I couldn't find answers in the change notes:

1. What exactly changed from 8.6.5 to 9.0.1 that introduced this incompatibility?
2. Is `xs@(~(x:xt))` really the best way to write this pattern, or is there a preferred way over this?

Comment: Does `~xs@(x:xt)` work?

Comment: @chepner No, then the `x:xt` pattern match is not irrefutable anymore, e.g. `f []` throws an error and doesn't just return `[]`.

Comment: @chepner as long as the list is nonempty, it would work!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for asking opinion-based questions. I don't think question 2 can be answered objectively. Maybe you can change it to something like "are there any other ways to write the same pattern?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The changes to the handling of ~ and @ in GHC 9.0 are described [here](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/migration/9.0#whitespace-sensitive-and-). Quoting from the migration guide:

> GHC 9.0 implements Proposal 229, which means that the !, ~, and @ characters are more sensitive to preceding and trailing whitespace than they were before. As a result, some things which used to parse one way will now parse differently (or throw a parse error).

Answer (score 3):

Adding parentheses (`variable@(~pattern)`) is a good solution. Alternatively, you could use a `let` or `where` binding, or a separate lazy `case`:

1. ```
   rehead :: a -> [a] -> [a]
   rehead x' xs0 = x' : xs
     where
       _x : xs = xs0
   ```
2. ```
   rehead :: a -> [a] -> [a]
   rehead x' xs0 = let
    _x : xs = xs0
    in x' : xs
   ```
3. ```
   {-# Language PatternGuards #-}

   rehead :: a -> [a] -> [a]
   rehead x' xs0
     | let _x : xs = xs0
     = x' : xs
   ```

   This can be very helpful if you want to use these bindings in subsequent guards.
4. ```
   rehead :: a -> [a] -> [a]
   rehead x' xs0 = case xs0 of
     ~(_x : xs) -> x' : xs
   ```

All of these options are maximally lazy:

- `head (rehead 5 [1, 2])`
- = `head (rehead 5 [])`
- = `head (rehead 5 undefined)`
- = `5`

If you’re using `{-# Language Strict #-}`, then you must write the `let`/`where` bindings as `~(_x : xs) = xs0` to allow `[]`, and the list parameter binding as `~xs0` to allow `undefined`; to get an *irrefutable* pattern (not just lazy) with `case`, you must write `~(~(_x : xs))`.